# Javascript websocket messages are cut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I'm using javascript websocket to send messages on a c server using NoPoll Websocket library.

When I send messages longer than 2920 chars my message is cut and I receive 2 differents packet on the server.

The most awkard is my second packet is longer than 2920 chars. For example :

```
socket.send(8000charsMessage) ----> packet1 : 2920 chars + packet2 : 5080 chars
socket.send(12000charsMessage) ----> packet1 : 2920 chars + packet2 : 9080 chars
```

I tested this with another socket server and I had the exact same behaviour so it seems thats the problem is about my javascript implementation.

This is how I initiate websocket :

```
this.http.get(app_url)
      .subscribe(res => {

        if (res['status'] !== 'OK')
          reject(res);

        if (WebSocket) {
          this._socket = new WebSocket(socket_url);
          if (this._socket === null) {
            reject(res);
          }
        [...]
        }
    }
```

And this is how I send packets :

```
this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(packet));
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: It looks like you're seeing packet fragmentation at the TCP level and a webSocket library that does not properly recombine the fragmented packets back into one message (like it's supposed to).